# magento programmatically build category tree

Tags: php, magento

I want to add the category tree into select multiple options control

I search lot on this got [this link](http://pragneshkaria.com/programatically-add-category-tree-outside-magento-with-jquery-tree-view/)

but it gives me output in ul li structure as follows

[image]

but I want this tree structure into select multiple options

can any one knows what to do changes in the link code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Preparing array:

```
public function getCategoriesArray() {

    $categoriesArray = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSort('path', 'asc')
            ->load()
            ->toArray();

    $categories = array();
    foreach ($categoriesArray as $categoryId => $category) {
        if (isset($category['name']) && isset($category['level'])) {
            $categories[] = array(
                'label' => $category['name'],
                'level'  =>$category['level'],
                'value' => $categoryId
            );
        }
    }

    return $categories;
}
```

Displaying in form:

```
    $fieldset->addField('categories', 'multiselect', array(
        'label' => $this->__('Categories'),
        'name' => 'categories',
        'values' => Mage::getModel(...)->getCategoriesArray(),
    ));
```

Comment: thanks for this but how can I use addField() into my custom form 
I want to assign the category tree structure in <select> with multiple control

Comment: Use (foreach(Mage::getModel(...)->getCategoriesArray() as $category)) and create your multiselect manually.

Comment: ok thanks can I get the category level using getCategoriesArray() function?

Comment: yes. add $category['level'] to categories array. Have a look - I changed answer

Comment: sorry but how to get only active categories using getCategoriesArray() function?

Comment: Use ->addAttributeToSort method

Comment: I added ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', array('eq'=>'1')) 
and it works